# Two-branched data flow network does not complete

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

This data flow network has a single bifurcation and produces the correct text output with proper results. Why does it not complete?

```
            // Connect multiple blocks
            // source -> convertToDouble -> multiply -> multiplyBuffer -> summation -> writeOut
            //                                                        |-> multiply2 -> writeListOut
            var source = new BufferBlock<List<int>>();
            var convertToDouble = new TransformBlock<List<int>, List<double>>((List<int> l) =>
            {
                return l.Select(_l => (double)_l).ToList();
            });
            source.LinkTo(convertToDouble);
            Func<List<double>, List<double>> multiplyFunc = (List<double> l) =>
            {
                return l.Select(_l => _l * 10.0).ToList();
            };
            var multiply = new TransformBlock<List<double>, List<double>>(multiplyFunc);
            convertToDouble.LinkTo(multiply);
            var multiplyBuffer = new BroadcastBlock<List<double>>((List<double> l) =>
            {
                return l;
            });
            multiply.LinkTo(multiplyBuffer);
            var summation = new TransformBlock<List<double>, double>((List<double> l) =>
            {
                return l.Sum();
            });
            multiplyBuffer.LinkTo(summation);
            var writeOut = new ActionBlock<double>((double d) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing out: " + d.ToString());
            });
            summation.LinkTo(writeOut);
            var multiply2 = new TransformBlock<List<double>, List<double>>(multiplyFunc);
            multiplyBuffer.LinkTo(multiply2);
            var writeListOut = new ActionBlock<List<double>>((List<double> l) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing list out: " + string.Join(", ", l.Select(_l => 
                    _l.ToString()).ToList()));
            });
            multiply2.LinkTo(writeListOut);

            source.Post(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000);
                Console.WriteLine("posting 2nd...");
                source.Post(new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 });
                source.Complete();
            });

            // Never completes
            try
            {
                writeOut.Completion.Wait();
                writeListOut.Completion.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                ex.Handle(e =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.GetType().Name, e.Message);
                    return true;
                });
            }
```

I've noticed if the `Completion.wait()` calls are omitted, then the program returns. There are no errors to be observed upon execution of the network.

Sample output:

Writing list out: 100, 200, 300
Writing out: 60
posting 2nd...
Writing out: 150
Writing list out: 400, 500, 600
(hangs)

Expected output:

Writing list out: 100, 200, 300
Writing out: 60
posting 2nd...
Writing out: 150
Writing list out: 400, 500, 600
(returns)

Comment: Can you supply some sample input and output? Also, What's the signature of the method?  We need to be able to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question, but the input is specified in the `source.Post()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TPL, source completion is not passed along to other blocks by default.

You need to construct a `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.DataflowLinkOptions` and set its `PropagateCompletion` property to `true`, and then pass that into the your invocations of `LinkTo`.

Alternately you can call the `Complete` method on all of your blocks sequentially.